# Programming: Equivalent function but different(ly optimized) implemention and automatic (cached) choice before each execution - How?

Tags: java, optimization

A function may work on CPU another on GPU, but both do the same job.

Sure, you want to use the GPU-solution (assuming it's faster), but it is not available on -for example- let's say the older OpenGL version.

Instead of programming a check (if available then use "this" else "that") on each function call, you may want to just call one function trough a reference bound to this function call.

---

To go further into optimization, imagine 4 solutions:

- CPU + optimized for small pictures
- CPU + optimized for big pictures
- GPU + optimized for small pictures
- GPU + optimized for big pictures

Now, not only do you (as a programmer) have to eliminate 2 possibilities depending on old/new "OpenGL version", you also have to choose one of the 2 remaining possibilities depending on usage.

Some calls only have small or big pictures as function parameters, but in others places of your code, you need to choose which function they want to call depending on the picture-parameter's values.
- For 4x4 pixel pictures or small lookup-tables even the CPU-solution could be the fastest (lower overhead)

---

One solution could be to make a function from which code paths split and lead to optimized functions.
This works for the same package, not for different packages providing the same function (example: standard-library vs driver-library/hooks)

Another solution could be to write jet another package which incorporates the used ones and chooses the function optimized for certain task.
Jet another -even uglier- solution could be to update each function call by hand.

---

But the solution I am searching uses a function reference for each call given to the function at program-loading time, depending on hardware or software environment.

It should even be able to change when dependency-libraries load or unload.
(For example: a new version of the other library is installed, the old one uninstalled while your program is running - or waiting during execution of another thread on this CPU-core)

The program shouldn't bother if there is just 1 or more functions under this name. It should bother what's the fastest to execute.

---

Example:

- package Pictures; //has averageRedValue( byte[height][width][RGB] )
- package Images; //has averageRedValue( byte[height][width][RGB] ) too

If they both give the same result, why should the programmer care about which one is used?
He wants the fast solution or an option read from a settings-file.

And the end-user wants a simple option to choose the same functions as used in a past date - which asks for version control and rollback features

---

Please tell me if you have seen a solution or an idea where to look at.

Comment: How is your program supposed to know which is the fastest implementation?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

This is all rather confused, but for the normal case, the solution is trivial: Write an interface containing the needed methods and make sure that only the best implementation gets loaded.

The JIT determines that there's just one such implementation ([Class Hierarchy Analysis](http://web.cs.ucla.edu/%7Epalsberg/tba/papers/dean-grove-chambers-ecoop95.pdf)) and calls the proper method directly.

> It should even be able to change when dependency-libraries load or unload.

Java can't do this efficiently. Whenever a second implementation gets loaded, the optimized code must be thrown away and the methods get recompiled. The conditional branch is still pretty cheap, with more implementations loaded its gets [slower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_caching#Megamorphic_inline_caching).

There's no way to unload a class without using some classloader magic.

What do you need it for?

Comment: When I don't know if byte or float values are given, it's common to use code branches . But I don't want to rewrite code doing essentially the same. An example: giving a class multiple modules which are ordered in memory as Structures of Arrays instead of Arrays of Structures but can use the same functions; Another example: when I implement multiple interfaces with equal functions under different names with just different variable types («5x readByte() or readInt()»  instead of saying "use bytes/ints" and «5x read()»).